Combining animations
How is it possible to combine several animations in the same graph?
Let's say I have the following animations (each shows how a graph evolves in time), and one to show them all in the same movie.
Animate[Plot[u[x/x0[t], t], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}], {t, 0, 1}]

Animate[Plot[ub[x/x0[t], t], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}], {t, 0, 1}]

I used Show but that didn't work.

If both animations depend on same slider variable, you can combine them into one Animate using Grid. So instead of
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}]
Animate[Plot[Cos[x + a]^2, {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}]

You could do
Animate[Grid[{
   {Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}]},
   {Plot[Cos[x + a]^2, {x, 0, 10}]}}
  ], {a, 0, 5}]


But may be you meant this:
Animate[
 p1 = Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
 p2 = Plot[Cos[x + a]^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
 Show[p1, p2]
 , {a, 0, 5}]


ps. You could also look at using Manipulate as it is much more powerful and more flexible to use than Animate.

Is it possible to add a legend for different colours in the last case?

Yes, You can use any Mathematica commands inside. For this case, might be easier to use one Plot with PlotLegends->"Expressions"
Animate[
 Plot[{Sin[x + a], Cos[x + a]^2}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
 , {a, 0, 5}]

Or you can write your own legend expression.


Is it possible to add a legend for different colours in the last case?
